# How do I use nested For loops to print array values within an array on new lines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to get the numbers from these arrays within an array to print on new lines, but can't figure out how to refer to them in order to print them to the console. What am I missing here?

```
var numbers = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19],
    [20],
    [21,22,23,24,25,26],
    [27,28,29,30]
];

for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<numbers[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(numbers[i].j); //The problem is with this j here I suspect...
    }
}
```

Comment: console.log(numbers[i][j]

Comment: Thank you much to all for helping me figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numbers[i].j accesses the property j for each array in numbers, you want numbers[i][j] which accesses element j in the array numbers[i]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<numbers[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(numbers[i][j]); //The problem is with this j here I suspect...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should read this way instead:

```
var numbers = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19],
    [20],
    [21,22,23,24,25,26],
    [27,28,29,30]
];

for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<numbers[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(numbers[i][j]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
console.log(numbers[i][j]);
```